# I have made a wordcloud using python and I want to look at the words in the wordcloud and if necessary, remove them from the image

Tags: python-3.x, list, word-cloud

So basically, I have a file where I have a few lists which I want to use to see if the words are present in a dictionary I have been given, and if yes, form a wordcloud out of it. Now after looking at the wordcloud I want to remove some useless words from the image, is this something you guys can help me with?

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import module1
import module2

lst = input('Which list?')


a = module2.diction

c = None
if lst == 'list1':
    c=module2.list1
if lst == 'list2':
    c=module2.list2

#print(c)
#doing stuff with the dictionary I had
for name, numb in a.items():
    for key in numb:
        key = key * numb[key]
        a[name] = key
#print(sample)
quad = ({key : a[key] for key in a if key in c})
#print(quad)

wc = WordCloud(background_color="white",width=1000,height=1000,colormap="copper", relative_scaling=0.5,
normalize_plurals=False).generate_from_frequencies(quad)

# Plot

plt.figure()
plt.ion()
plt.imshow(wc, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.margins(x=0, y=0)
plt.axis('off')
plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
plt.ioff()
plt.show()


u = input('Enter the words: ')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove something from a dictionary you can use the following syntax:

```
del dictonary[word]
```

That will delete the word from the dictionary, so if you come across the word `the` and want to remove it you could use

```
del c['the']
```